# QtPositioning 5.3, QML PositionSource Returning no Data on ios 8.1?

Tags: ios, qt, qml

I'm building a simple photo app and need the GPS coordinates of the current picture. I've followed the basics of creating and checking the PositionSource element in qml (and it seems fine). But when I access the coordinates and timestamp it gives me invalid time and NaN.

I've added the import QtPositioning 5.3 in qml and in the .pro file  the QT += qml quick positioning

Heres my PositionSource Element

```
PositionSource {
        id: src
        active: true
        preferredPositioningMethods: PositionSource.SatellitePositioningMethods

        Component.onCompleted: {
            src.start()
            src.update()
            var supPos  = "Unknown"
            if (src.supportedPositioningMethods == PositionSource.NoPositioningMethods) {
                 supPos = "NoPositioningMethods"
            } else if (src.supportedPositioningMethods == PositionSource.AllPositioningMethods) {
                 supPos = "AllPositioningMethods"
            } else if (src.supportedPositioningMethods == PositionSource.SatellitePositioningMethods) {
                 supPos = "SatellitePositioningMethods"
            } else if (src.supportedPositioningMethods == PositionSource.NonSatellitePositioningMethods) {
                 supPos = "NonSatellitePositioningMethods"
            }
            console.log("Position Source Loaded || Supported: "+supPos+" Valid: "+valid)
        }

        onPositionChanged: {
            var coord = src.position.coordinate;
            console.log("Coordinate:", coord.longitude, coord.latitude);
        }
    }
```

When I run the app on iOS 8.1 (iphone 4s) it gives me AllPositioningMethods and Valid True. But when I call:

```
function getPos() {
    var coord = src.position.coordinate;
    posTest.text = "Coordinates lat:"+coord.latitude+" lon:"+coord.longitude+" time:"+src.position.timestamp
}
```

It jus gives me NaN NaN and Invalid Timestamp...
Anyone tried using the PositionSource element on a real device and have it working... ? I'll try it on other devices soon... ios and android..

Update****
Seems to work fine on Android 4.4.4 (MotoX)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. Two critical items:

1. Make sure `QT += positioning` is included in the build in your `.pro` file. It doesn't seem to be required on Android but is required on iOS.
2. Make sure to setup a custom Info.plist for your project (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/platform-notes-ios.html) and that it includes one of:

---

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Explanation to user.</string>
```

or

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Explanation to user.</string>
```

Whichever one you add is what it will prompt for.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you have not enabled Location Service for the application . You can enable that in settings . 
http://www.imore.com/how-grant-restrict-access-location-iphone-ipad

Comment: I've tried this. Maybe it has something to do with the new location auth protocol. Maybe theres a missing entry on info.plist, or the Qt Location isn't sending the proper request.

Comment: @Gabriel Hove you got it working? I am facing problems getting it working on ios. But it works perfectly of android